# Isomorphism of simple extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I have to show that if $\alpha$ has the minimal polynomial $t^2-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\beta$ has the minimal polynomial $t^2-4t+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ then the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta):\mathbb{Q}$ are isomorphic.

However the only way that I know how to show that two extensions are isomorphic is if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ had the same minimal polynomial, which they don't?

Cheers Folks

Comment: You mean isomorphic as rational vector spaces...?

Comment: $t^2-4t+3$ is reducible over $\Bbb{Q}$. It is impossible for it to be the minimal polynomial of anything.

Comment: @ChrisEagle It was supposed to be $t^2-4t+2$ sorry

Answer (score 5):

Hint:

If we imagine both fields embedded in $\Bbb C$, then clearly $\alpha$ must be $\pm\sqrt 2$ while by the quadratic formula $\beta = \frac{4\pm\sqrt{16-8}}{2}=2\pm\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution: Choose a common extension, say $\mathbb{C}$. Then $0 = \beta^2-4\beta+2 = (\beta-2)^2-2$ implies $\beta-2=\pm \alpha$, hence $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ have a minimal polynomial $t^2-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\beta$ have a minimal polynomial $t^2+4t+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. We need to show that the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha): \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta): \mathbb{Q}$ are isomorphic. It is enough to show that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be written as a linear combination of one another because of the definition of a simple extension.

If $\alpha$ have a minimal polynomial $t^2-2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then $\alpha=\pm \sqrt{2}$. Similarly, if $\beta$ have a minimal polynomial $t^2+4t+2$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, by the quadratic formula
$$\beta=\frac{4\pm \sqrt{16-8}}{2}=\frac{4\pm 2\sqrt{2}}{2}=2\pm \sqrt{2},$$
then $\beta=2\pm 2$. Note that $$0=\beta^2-4\beta+2=\beta^2-4\beta+4+(-4+2)=(\beta-2)^2-2.$$ So $$(\beta-2)^2=2 \iff \beta-2=\pm \sqrt{2}=\beta-2=\pm \alpha.$$ Hence $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(\beta).$ (i.e. The extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha): \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta): \mathbb{Q}$ are isomorphic.)

Answer (score 0):

Consider all elements you can obtain using addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division with the rationals and $\alpha$ and deduce that you can obtain all elements of $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$. This shows that $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ is a subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$. The do the converse to show they are actually equal.